# Show $\| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \| \le | \Im(\lambda) |^{-1}$, $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ WITHOUT functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof, functional-calculus

> **Lemma (Resolvent bound).** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A \in L(H)$ linear, bounded and self-adjoint and $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. Then $$\| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \| \le | \Im(\lambda) |^{-1}.$$

I have been able to prove this with the continuous functional calculus, as I show below (is this proof correct?) but I wondered if there's a way to show it **without functional calculus**.

Here is one proof of lemma 1 using the continuous functional calculus:
*Proof.*
As $A = A^*$ we have $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb R$, implying $\lambda \not\in \sigma(A)$.
    Therefore,
    \begin{equation*}
    f: \sigma(A) \to \mathbb C, \ 
    x \mapsto \frac{1}{x - \lambda}
\end{equation*}
    is continuous and by the continuous functional calculus we have
    \begin{align*}
    \| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \|
    & = \| f(A) \|
    = \sup_{\mu \in \sigma(A)} | f(\mu) | 
    = \sup_{\mu \in \sigma(A)} \frac{1}{| \mu - \lambda |} \\
    & = \frac{1}{\inf_{\mu \in \sigma(A)} | \mu - \lambda |}
    = \frac{1}{\inf_{\mu \in \sigma(A)} \sqrt{(\mu - \Re(\lambda))^2 + \Im(\lambda)^2}} \\
    & \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Im(\lambda)^2}}
    = \frac{1}{| \Im(\lambda) |},
\end{align*}
    where equality holds if $\Re(\lambda) \in \sigma(A)$. $\square$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=A^*$, then $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is real for all $x\in H$. So
$$
          -\Im\lambda\|x\|^2=\Im \langle (A-\lambda I)x,x\rangle \\
        |\Im\lambda|\|x\|^2 \le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|\|x\| \\
         |\Im\lambda|\|x\| \le \|(A-\lambda I)x\| \\
         |\Im\lambda|\|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}x\| \le \|x\| \\
           \|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}x\|\le \frac{1}{|\Im\lambda|}\|x\| \\
          \|(A-\lambda I)^{-1}\|\le\frac{1}{|\Im\lambda|}
$$

Comment: $|\Im\langle (A-\lambda I)x,x\rangle| \le |\langle (A-\lambda I)x,x\rangle| \le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|\|x\|$

Comment: @ViktorGlombik : If $\|x\| \le \|Tx\|$ for all $x$, and if $T$ is invertible, then $x=T^{-1}y$ is a valid choice of $x$.