# Can we save this proof of a resolvent bound without using the (continuous) functional calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof, spectral-theory

> **Lemma 1 (Resolvent bound).** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A \in L(H)$ linear, bounded and self-adjoint and $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. Then $$\| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \| \le | \Im(\lambda) |^{-1}.$$

I have shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3565604/545914) a way to prove lemma 1 with functional calculus and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3565954/545914) to the above mentioned question is way to show this result without functional analysis.

A friend suggested to me the following proof of lemma 1, which heavily relies on the following lemma:

> **Lemma 2 (Invertibility).**
>   Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces and $T \in L(E,F)$ be bijective.
>   Let $T^{-1} \in L(F,E)$ be the inverse of $T$ and $S \in L(E,F)$ such that
>   $$
> \| S - T \|
> < \| T^{-1} \|^{-1}
> $$
>   Then $S$ is also invertible.

*Proof.*
Assume $\| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \| > | \Im(\lambda) |^{-1}$.
As $\sigma(A) \ne \emptyset$ (Gelfand-Mazur), let $\mu \in \sigma(A)$.
As $A$ is self-adjoint, it's spectrum is real, so $| \lambda - \mu | \ge | \Im(\lambda) |$.
Thus
$$
\| (A - \mu I) - (\lambda - \mu) I \|
= \| A - \lambda I \|
< | \Im(\lambda) |
= | \lambda - \mu |
=  \| ((\mu - \lambda) I)^{-1} \|^{-1}.
$$
By lemma 2 $A - \mu I$ is invertible, which contradicts $\mu \in \sigma(A)$.  $\ \square$

Unfortunately, I *don't* think that we can conclude
$$
\| (A - \lambda I)^{-1} \| > | \Im(\lambda) |^{-1}
\implies \| A - \lambda I \| < | \Im(\lambda) |.
$$
Is there a way to save this proof idea?

---